# How can I iterate through array of arrays and check if they have a value of another array + prefix?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, one for a object I called server and other for a client, as below:

```
server_array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
client_array = [['not_test1', 'test3'], ['test2', 'test4']]
```

What I need to do is, return just the arrays inside the client array that haven't any matching values with the prefix not_ after, for clarification:
Inside position 0 of the client_array, I have a not_test1 inside it, which is the opposite of test1 inside the server_array, so this array should be filtered.

The output so would be:

```
client_array = [['test2', 'test4']]
```

I currently tried a solution using map and filter, but cannot come with anything that iterates properly in the arrays, I didn't tried to do a normal for loop because I thought it would take too much time to execute.

Comment: "I currently tried a solution using map and filter" ...can you show us? [Preferably within a running snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If `not_test1` is in the server array, would your expected result be  `[['not_test1', 'test3'], ['test2', 'test4']]` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
server_array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
client_array = [['not_test1', 'test3'], ['test2', 'test4']];
client_array
    .filter(c => !c.some(i => i.startsWith('not_') &&
                 server_array.includes(i.replace(/^not_/, ''))));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as simple as this. You filter out of the resulting array those arrays that have at least one match with the predicate
`` e => `not_${e}` == element ``

```js
const result = client_array.filter(array => array.filter(
    element => server_array.find(e => `not_${e}` == element)).length === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const server_array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
const client_array = [['not_test1', 'test3'], ['test2', 'test4']]
      
const res = client_array.filter(e =>                 // filter client_array
  e.some(x =>                                        // filter sub arrays if any item
    !x.startsWith('not_')                            // check if sub array element starts with "not_"
    && !server_array.includes(x.replace('not_', '')) // check if server_array contains not negatated item
  )
)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, you can remove `.flat()` to don't flatten the result.

```js
server_array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
client_array = [['not_test1', 'test3'], ['test2', 'test4']]

let res = client_array.filter(e => !e[0].startsWith('not_')).flat();
```